# Deny access to a port from localhost on OSX

Tags: macos, firewall, localhost

I want to test a fallback strategy for my memcached driver (in case port is protected by firewall). How can I deny access to a specific port, on 127.0.0.1?

Comment: depending on which version of MacOS you are using, use either jaume's answer (= you are on 10.7 or later) or mine (you are on 10.6).

Comment: @FlorenzKley: Thank you both for the answers, I upvoted both of them. I decided to accept answer, as I am on OSX Snow Leopard :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example for Mac OS X 10.6 (Snow Leopard)

to deny connections to localhost, port SSH (= 22, read from `/etc/services`):

```
sudo ipfw add deny tcp from any to localhost ssh
```

Comment: ipfw is deprecated in OSX 10.7 and OSX 10.8 and no longer available on OSX 10.9

Comment: that's why it says "Example for Mac OS X 10.6" in my answer...

Answer (score 22):

You can use `pfctl`.

OS X 10.7 "Lion" and later use the [OpenBSD PF](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) (Packet Filter). A pseudo-device called `/dev/pf` allows user space tools to configure the packet filter. The command `pfctl` provides most of the functionality.

To filter port 1234 on the loopback interface you can use a rule like this:

```
block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234
```

This rules blocks all inbound/outbound traffic on `lo0` for port 1234 (`quick` means in this context that if this rule matches, no further rule should be applied).

The command to load the rule in PF is:

```
(sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null; echo "block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234") | sudo pfctl -nf -
```

Command `pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null` lists all current rules (and sends the pretty annoying error message `No ALTQ support in kernel ALTQ related functions disabled` to `/dev/null`). The `echo` adds the rule above to the output, which is piped to `pfctl`. Option `-n` means *don't apply, just check*.

If there's no error message (apart from the aforementioned `No ALTQ support` message and the warning `pfctl: Use of -f option, could result in flushing of rules present in the main ruleset added by the system at startup`), you can apply the rule:

```
(sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null; echo "block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234") | sudo pfctl -f - 2>/dev/null
```

This command differs from the previous one in that I removed `-n`. Note that you may have to add option `-e` to enable the packet filter (thanks for your [comment](https://superuser.com/questions/505128/deny-access-to-a-port-from-localhost-on-osx/505209?noredirect=1#comment1193213_505209), [casey](https://superuser.com/users/268078/casey)): `(sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null; echo "block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234") | sudo pfctl -e -f - 2>/dev/null`

You can list now the rules to check it has been added properly:

```
sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null
(...)
block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234
```

When you're done you can **delete the rule**:

1. either loading the original set of rules:

   ```
   sudo pfctl -f /etc/pf.conf
   ```
2. or removing the rule in a similar manner the rule was added:

   ```
   (sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null | fgrep -v "block drop quick on lo0 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234") | sudo pfctl -f -
   ```

(I've tested the whole procedure on OS X 10.8.2 "Mountain Lion" and worked flawlessly.)

You can find more information in this excellent introduction: http://nomoa.com/bsd/gateway/pf/valid/pfctl.html.

`ipfw` is still included in OS X 10.7 and 10.8 but is deprecated:

```
IPFW(8)                   BSD System Manager's Manual                  IPFW(8)

NAME
     ipfw -- IP firewall and traffic shaper control program (DEPRECATED)

SYNOPSIS
(...)

DESCRIPTION
     Note that use of this utility is DEPRECATED. Please use pfctl(8) instead.
```

Comment: on a fresh computer you may actually have to enable it also. just change `-f` to `-ef`

Comment: @casey Thanks, I edited my answer to add the information in your comment.

Comment: Nice answer, and amazingly terrible horrible interface. Whoever wrote `pfctl` should be sent back to school.