# How do I block port 1234 in localhost without killing the process in MacOS

Tags: networking, macos, iptables, port

I have a requirement to close a port without killing the process to test out a certain fallback scenario. I am using MacOS and I am unable to figure out how to do this, can someone please help?

I tried setting iptable rule using pfctl, but that did not work
(Ref - [Deny access to a port from localhost on OSX](https://superuser.com/questions/505128/deny-access-to-a-port-from-localhost-on-osx)) :

```
(sudo pfctl -sr 2>/dev/null; echo "block drop quick on 127.0.0.1 proto tcp from any to any port = 1234") | sudo pfctl -e -f - 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: What happened when you ran the `pfctl` command ?

Comment: Review this solution to see if it helps in your situation: https://superuser.com/questions/505128/deny-access-to-a-port-from-localhost-on-osx

Comment: @Brian: This is the link in the post.

Comment: @harrymc, my bad.

Comment: @harrymc , it got added in the rule but port was still open

Comment: Please don't cross-post to multiple SE sites. Pick one & stick to it, or flag for migration. 
[Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/) - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/461564/how-do-i-block-port-1234-in-localhost-without-killing-the-process-in-macos